Condition for $E[X\log^+(X)]$ to be finite for a random variable $X$
I’m trying to prove the following statement, for a random variable $X$ on some probability space:
$$\mathbb{E}[X\log^+(X)] \lt \infty
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad 
\int_1^\infty \int_1^\infty \mathbb{P}[X \gt uv] \,du \,dv \lt \infty
$$
Here $\log^+(x) \equiv \max(\log(x), 0)$.
So far, I have tried rewriting the integrals in terms of characteristic functions, but I haven’t been able to prove the statement.

$\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}$
Define the function
$$
\phi(x) = \int_1^\infty \frac{(x-v)_+}{v} \, dv = \begin{cases}
x \log x + 1 - x & x > 1\\ 
0 & x \leq 1 
\end{cases}.
$$
Your claim reduces to showing that

If $X > 1$ almost surely, then $\mathbb{E} X \log X < \infty$ if and only if $\mathbb{E} \phi(X) < \infty$.


Proof that claim suffices:
Recall for nonnegative random variables $Y$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y > t)\, dt.
$$
It follows easily from this fact (take $Y = (X/v - 1)_+$) that
$$
\int_1^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > uv) \, du = \frac{1}{v}\mathbb{E}[(X - v)_+].
$$
Therefore by Fubini's theorem, we have
$$
\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > uv)\, du dv = \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)].
$$
Since $\phi(x) = x \log^+ x = 0$ when $x \leq 1$, we may further assume that $X > 1$ without loss of generality. Hence, it suffices to establish the claim.

Proof of claim: The direction "$\Rightarrow$" is obvious. For "$\Leftarrow$", fix $t > 1$ and notice
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X \log X] &= \mathbb{E}[X \log X \1_{X \leq t}] + \mathbb{E}[X \log X \1_{X > t}] \\
&\leq t \log t + \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)] \, 
\sup_{x > t} \frac{x \log x}{\phi(x)}.
\end{align*}
Here we used the fact that $\phi(x) \geq 0$, and $x \log x$ is increasing for $x > 1$. By differentiation, $x \mapsto (x \log x)/\phi(x)$ is decreasing for $x > 1$. Hence,
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \log X] \leq \inf_{t > 1}\Big\{  t \log t  + \frac{t \log t}{\phi(t)} \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]\Big\} < \infty, 
$$
as needed.

For the $\Leftarrow$ implication, you could have a convergent integral that splits into two pieces that aren’t convergent.

If $a = \mathbb{E}[X \log^+(X)], b = \mathbb{E}[(X-1)_+]$ are such that $a - b$ is finite then how can it be that either are infinite?

Couldn’t you have something like this: $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} , dx$ is finite, but $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} , dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x} , dx - \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} , dx$. So even though the integral on the left is finite, I can split it into two pieces which are both infinite.

I've gone ahead and provided a different argument, one which simply bounds the expectation from above.
